# Spring Specification and Pageable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, specifications

How can I use `Specification` and `Pageable` together?

**personelRepository.java**

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM PersonelEntity e ")
List<PersonelEntity> findData(Specification<PersonelEntity>  test, Pageable pageable);
```

**personelService.java**

```
public List<PersonelEntity> filteredData(Specification<PersonelEntity> filter,Pageable  pageable){
    List<PersonelEntity> filteredData = personelRepository.findData(filter,pageable);
    return filteredData;
}
```

**personelController.java**

```
Pageable reqCount = new PageRequest(0, 10);
Specification<PersonelEntity> filter = new FilterSpecification<PersonelEntity>(new SearchCriteria("name", "=","lux"));
personels = personelService.findData(filter,reqCount);
```

When I run it I get an error like this. But if I call findAll() function separately like findAll(Pageable page) and findAll(Specification filter) it works. But I can not use it together.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:502) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:692) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:141) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: How you use this, can you provide some code please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solve by editing personelService.java and delete findData function on personelRepository. I use springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository findAll() function and it works.

```
public List<PersonelEntity> filteredData (Specification<PersonelEntity> spec, Pageable pageable){
    Page<PersonelEntity> pageData = personelRepository.findAll(spec,pageable);
    List<PersonelEntity> filteredData = pageData.getContent();
    return filteredData;
}
```

Comment: If I delete `findAll` from me repository, there is a compile error saying `Cannot resolve method findAll(Specification<>, Pageable)`. Is that method in your case inherited from a spring interface? If so, which one?

Comment: A little late to the party maybe, but I found it in the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface

Comment: I added `extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<PersonelEntity>` to my  existing Repository. And it worked like a charm.