# spring repository data dynamic query for filter multi parameters

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a Entity class that has 5 parameters, name,family, email, address , Age. Searching these individually or in groups should be dynamic. This is in the situation that if I want to write alone, the whole space is taken.How can I write to them a dynamic queue?

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity1, Long> {
    Page<DirectTopup> findAllByName(Pageable pageable, String name);
    Page<DirectTopup> findAllByNameAndFamily(Pageable pageable, String name, , String family);
    Page<DirectTopup> findAllByNameAndFamilyAndEmail(Pageable pageable, String name, , String family, String email);

...

    Page<DirectTopup> findAllByNameAndFamilyAndEmail(Pageable pageable, String name, , String family, String email, String address, int age)

}
```

For each possible call, Parametrary is Zer and Nal, or nothing at all.
Please advise

```
if (name != null && family == null && email == null && address == null && age ==null){
myRepository.findAllByName(new PageRequest(page, size, direction, propertie), name);
}

if (name == null && family != null && email == null && address == null && age ==null){
    myRepository.findAllByFamily(new PageRequest(page, size, direction, propertie), family);
    }
```

... and All parameters

All separated values separate.

```
    if (name != null && family != null && email != null && address == null && age ==null){
        myRepository.findAllByNameAndFamilyAndEmail(new PageRequest(page, size, direction, propertie), name, family, email);
        }
....
```

And combine them (multi parameters):

and it may be a combination of parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **specification Interface** for this scenario. 
Go through this [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/specifications.html)

once you go through above link then use this predicate
for dynamically filtering columns use this predicate :

```
@Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity1> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) 
        {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();


            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name))
            {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("name")), "%"+name.toLowerCase()+"%"));
            }

            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(family))
            {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("family")), "%"+family.toLowerCase()+"%"));
            }

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        }
```

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447687/spring-specification-and-pageable) will be helpful as well.

Comment: This suggestion is not right at all.However, we will have a complete inquiry.The volume of queries increases.

Comment: May i know what does 'inquiry' mean? Do you mean in query?

Comment: "query", excuse me. @Pratik soni