# Is it possible to use and combine WHERE clauses in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm writing an app using Spring Boot, Spring Data. And I'm trying to implement a filtering feature based on different filter parameters.

I've discovered Spring Data REST framework which out of the box supports basic filtering operations, e.g.:

```
/myEntities?field1=value1&field2=value2&sort=field2,desc&size=10&page=2
```

In this case we just filter by 2 fields without any additional where clauses.

But what If I need a more complex filter with different number of where clauses, order, limit for my entities? The result query might look something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field1 != `value1` and (field1 != ` value2 `OR (field1 = `value3` AND filed2 < 3))
AND field2 != 99
```

Is it possible to achieve this combinations of different where clauses using built-in features of Spring Data Rest (sending all this stuff as http parameters)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to do what you are trying to achieve with something as simple as what you have now. But you could try using specifications with Pageable. 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452298/6279345) might be helpful

Comment: No. You're going to have to roll your own solution or maybe investigate if an OData implementation can handle this e.g. Olingo  https://www.baeldung.com/olingo and http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/csprd05/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-csprd05-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc14103640

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize your repository to have a search method with all required parameters. They will then be exposed to Spring Data Rest under the search resources, with all query parameters.

Something like:

```
@RestResource(path = "weirdFilter", rel = "weirdFilter")
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field1 != :value1 and (field1 != :value2 OR (field1 = :value3 AND field2 < 3))
AND field2 != 99")
public Page<Stuff> findByWeirdFilter(@Param("value1") String value1, @Param("value2") String value2, @Param("value3") String value3, Pageable p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've used Spring Data Jpa + RSQL (Rest Query Language) based on that [library](https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification)

It allows to execute any filtering logic with nested where clauses on the fly.
Filter itself is just a string: `String filter = "field1=='val1' and (field2=='val2' and (field3 > 56 or field4 > 23))";` so you can pass any filter (properly built in terms of rsql otherwise it won't be able to parse your request) and easily modify it if needed.

The lib itself translates the given filter to Specification or Predicator (you can choose) also it's quite easy to add `limit` and `orderBy` to the final request if you need it.